# UML association class and OOP languages

Tags: django, uml, class-diagram, model-associations, multiplicity

I am building a web application with Django, 
I did the design app with UML2.
i read that association class concept does not exist in object oriented programming languages, is that true ??
thank you.

class diagram

[image: class diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can implement that model relationship design as follows:

```
class Society(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    societies = models.ManyToManyField(Society, through='Employment', related_name='users', blank=True)

class Employment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('user', 'society')]
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    society = models.ForeignKey(Society, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: can you please clarify to me the need of 'societies = models.ManyToManyField' in User Class. Don't we just need to add user and society to Employment Class ?. thank you

Comment: You can do that too. However, your diagram shows a clear relationship between the two so I figured you'd want the ability to do `user.societies.all()`. Here are the docs that explain the ManyToManyField - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

Comment: thank you for your clarifications, really helped me  :)